# How to pronounce $<A| Im B>$?

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I'm studying linear control theory (by "Control theory for linear systems" by Trentelman et al.) and there appears  subspaces
$$
\langle A \vert im \, B\rangle = im \,B + A \,im\, B + \ \ldots \ + A^{n-1}\,im\,B
$$
and
$$
\langle ker \, C\vert  A\rangle= ker \, C \cap ker \, CA \cap \ \ldots \cap CA^{n-1}.
$$

Unfortunately, I'm unable to find how to pronounce the left part of this formulas. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would call them by their names, i.e. controllability and observability subspaces.

Comment: I actually do exactly this, but when using something like $\langle A+BF \vert im \, B \cap L \rangle$ it's rather inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

"<A|imB>": This represents the subspace formed by taking the images of $B$ under the powers of $A$. In simpler terms, it refers to the space spanned by the results obtained by applying $A$ to $B$ multiple times.

"<kerC|A>": This denotes the intersection of the kernel of $C$ with the powers of $A$. In simpler words, it represents the common elements shared between the null space of $C$ and the results obtained by applying $A$ multiple times.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  OP asked how to pronounce them